# Geometrical Applications of Complex Numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

> The complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ satisfying $$\dfrac{z_1+z_3}{z_2-z_3}=\dfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ are the vertices of a triangle which is:
>
> a) of area $0$
>
> b) equilateral
>
> c) right angled and isosceles
>
> d) obtuse angled

$$$$

All I got was that from the Rotation Theorem, $$\arg\left(\dfrac{z_1+z_3}{z_2-z_3}\right)=-\pi/3$$ and that $$|z_1+z_3|=|z_2-z_3|$$
$$$$
Could somebody please show me how to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: If the numerator were $z_1-z_3$ instead of $z_1+z_3$, then the answer would be (b), because the information you're given would imply that two of the sides have equal length and the angle between those two sides is $60^\circ$.

Comment: Hint: Shift the origin to any of $z_1, z_2, z_3$ to see the properties of triangle, as angles and sides are invariant under translation of origin.

Comment: You should edit your post: in fact it's $\frac{\text{z1}+\text{z3}}{\text{z2}-\text{z3}}=e^{-i\frac{\pi }{3}}$ and $\arg \left(\frac{\text{z1}+\text{z3}}{\text{z2}-\text{z3}}\right)=-\frac{\pi }{3}$. As @user21820, I don't think you can know much more about $z1,z2,z3$...

Comment: @mea43 Sir I tried for very long, but couldn't reach anywhere. Could you please help me?

Comment: @EddyKhemiri Edited, thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the problem. By what you have stated, we know that $(-z_1,z_2,z_3)$ are the vertices of an isosceles triangle with equal sides meeting at $120^\circ$. But then we don't know anything much about $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, because as you can see translating $(-z_1,z_2,z_3)$ around makes $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ change shape.